# Horipad Ultimate Local Multiplayer on tvOS

Tags: bluetooth, appletv, apple-id

I have two HORIPAD Ultimate controllers and would like to set them up for local multiplayer games on tvOS.

Both controllers pair to the AppleTV (4k), but they always both join in the same "position". They both have the leftmost LED lit to indicate player position 1. When paired this way, both controllers give input to the same player. None of the games with local multiplayer seem to trigger the event to "see" a second controller for activating a second player.

Is there some trick to get one controller to join in position 2?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try clearing pairing and re-pairing?

"To clear all pairings, hold the Bluetooth button and the MENU button together for at least 5 seconds"

See also all the apple TV requirements [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210414#atv) and the troubleshooting section at the end.

Comment: Yes, I've tried re-pairing several times. The AppleTV requirements state that up to 4 MFi controllers can be connected at once. That seems rather pointless if they are all on the same "channel". My guess is that it's a problem with the controller.